# BigQuery Share DataSets

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

In our organisation we want to share datasets with other team, for that i have created a `google-group` and added that group to one of the Bigquery dataset with `BigQuery Data Viewer`.

Once the user added to our google group, they are not able to search project on their google console, Do we need to provide any other permissions to our google group so that project should be visible on their console ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With BigQuery, there is 2 different parts: string the data and processing the data. The storage isn't expensive and you can host the data for others. When you process the data, you pay the volume of data that you process, and it could be expensive.

That's why there is public dataset that you request with your project:

- Google pay the storage of public dataset
- You (your current project) pay for the processing.

---

In your case, it's the same thing. You have a host project which host the data, and you shared the dataset with a group of users.

Now, this groups of user need to have a project, with the role BigQuery User, which allows them to run job and thus to process query (and to pay for this).

On this project, they have a button `+ ADD DATA`, click on it and then click on `PIN A PROJECT`. Browse to find the host project, select it and pin it. Only the viewable datasets per the users are displayed under the project.